# For in Javascript: alway return the same value

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a List menu like this:

And i want to generate [li] from my data.
I use a Javascript function:

```js
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var sidebar = $('#side_bar');
    var sidebar_entry = $('<li/>', {
    'html': (i+1),
    'click': function() {
      alert("Li "+i)
    },
    'mouseenter': function() {
      $(this).css('color', 'red');
    },
    'mouseleave': function() {
      $(this).css('color', '#999999');
    }
    }).appendTo(sidebar);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sidebar-nav" id="side_bar">
  <li class="sidebar-brand" style="font-weight: bold; color: #999999;">
    <h1>Places</h1>
  </li>
  <hr>
</ul>
```

But in result, all [li]'s click return alert(Li 9).

Why is it?

Comment: because by the time the click event is called, `i` will be 9 ... lookup closures

Comment: quick and dirty fix - `for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { (function(i) {` your current loop body `})(i); }`

Comment: You can also look into `this.innerHTML`

Comment: @Rajesh - what!?

Comment: @JaromandaX He is setting number as HTML, you he can access value from html as well. [Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/ygb8sa7d/)